# Spring boot and JavaMailSender NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

Im writing simple mailsender for my spring-boot application. However I'm having a problem with a bean creation. Here's my MailSender class

```
@Component
public class MailSender {
    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    public void send() {
        MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);
            helper.setTo("somemail@some.com");
            helper.setReplyTo("");
            helper.setFrom("me@email.com");
            helper.setSubject("Lorem ipsum");
            helper.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [...]");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {}
        javaMailSender.send(mail);
        System.out.println("Mail has been sent !");

    }

}
```

Next I'm trying to create autowired MailSender instance in main class and here's where i get the error

```
@SpringBootApplication

public class myApplication {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(myApplication.class);
    @Autowired
    private MailReceiver mailReceiver;
    @Autowired
    private MailSender ms;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(myApplication.class, "--debug"); 
    } 
...
//more code
```

And the error is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'myApplication': Injection 
of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private info.some.mail.MailSender
info.some.myApplication.ms; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [info.some.mail.MailSender]
```

Can you help me with that

EDIT:
Of course I have spring-boot-starter-mail included in my build.gradle file

Comment: Do you set `@ComponentScan correctly?

Comment: Doesn't @SpringBootApplication doing it for me ?

Comment: I've added it to my Main class but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: How does it looks like?

Comment: I've mentioned it above

Answer (score 0):

Ok I don't even know how is this possible but as soon I've changed class name from "MailSender" to whatever else - everything starts working perfectly